# how to tell which log4j is my java app using?

Tags: log4j

I have several java applications (running on Linux) that appear to specify a specific "log4j" version in the java executable....  For example:

<path to .../bin/java  -Xmx242M -XX:MaxPermSize=160M  blahblahblah:<path to log4j-core.jar:blahblah

The log4j version specified in the java executable is 1.2.17 (so...not vulnerable)

However, the vendor says the application uses log4j-core-2.9.1.jar (so... yes vulnerable)?

But if java is specifying the older version, why would the app be using the newer version?

How can I tell for sure which "log4j" is in use?

Answer (score 1):

Make a new folder then unzip the jar file into the folder. Then do Ctrl-F log4j and you will see jar files for log4j with the version on them.